# Unity3d and Photon cannot connect to Master Server

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I am currently running in a problem, when I want to connect to the Photon Server.

```
LoadBalancingClient client = new LoadBalancingClient();  
client.AppId = "*************************"; // myAppId
connectInProcess = client.ConnectToRegionMaster ("eu");     
Debug.Log(client.IsConnectedAndReady); **//Is False**
Debug.Log(client.IsConnected); **//Is True**
```

How does it come that one property is true and the other one false?
Am i even connected or do i have to do additional steps?

Greetings

Andreas

Answer (score 4):

From [the official API documentation](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/dotnet/current/class_exit_games_1_1_client_1_1_photon_1_1_load_balancing_1_1_load_balancing_client.html#a10751130a4c408c8b38df0debd0b1707):
`isConnected` returns true if you are connected to any server in any way.
`isConnectedAndReady` on the other hand returns true if the connection is ready for some operations.
Try calling the `.Service()` method on your `LoadBalancingClient`.